# Sourcetree fatal error during finish release - fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

We are using sourcetree and during finish release we are encountering fatal error as below. It is working fine for commits, merges, push. Earlier it was working for 'finish releases' as well.

fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have encountered similar issue with Sourcetree version 3.2.1 (225)

Below steps resolved the issue:

1. Go to 'Preferences'
2. Select tab 'Git'
3. In section 'Git version' select 'Use system git'
4. New window (locate your system git executable) opens. Select 'git' and click open.

This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 3):

For Android Studio,

Go to Android Studio --> Preferences --> Version Control --> Git --> **Enable 'Credentials Helper' option**.

It works for me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Update 5-FEB-2022**

if someone is still facing this in Android Studio
goto
VCS-> GIT -> Remotes
edit the origin and replace the url with :

```
https://<username>@github.com/<username>/<repo>.git
```

This worked for me!!